# UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime format 2012-12-20 07:15:18 +0000 without +0000

Tags: ios, datepicker, format

`UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime` returns an output in format

```
2012-12-20 07:15:18 +0000.
```

How can I remove the `+0000` from the output?

I wanted to make a screenshot, but yet my reputation is not enough, I hope it will clear my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDate *date = sender.date;
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];   // if you want to show the date to the user
    [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];   // if you want to show the date to the user
    // [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];  // if you want to use the date for your model

    NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
}
```

If you want to show the date to the user please use `setDateStyle:` and `setTimeStyle:`, because they are locale aware and produce the output in the correct format. 
If you need that date only for the back end (e.g. creating a file name) use `setDateFormat:`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this. Some of these are:

1) substitution of + 0000 by empty string

2) slicing the output until the (length - 5)

It requires creativity to develop more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code

```
NSString *calDate = @"2011-11-11 21:56:38 +0000";

NSDate *date = [[[NSDate alloc] init] retain];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];  

//                                   right here    ^

date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:calDate];

NSLog(@"date:%@", date);
```

Outputs:

```
2012-01-03 20:14:15.258 Craplet[38753:707] date:2011-11-11 21:56:38 +0000
```

Without the Z:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

It outputs:

```
2012-01-03 20:16:10.456 Craplet[38885:707] date:(null)
```

If the format cannot be matched to the date string, it returns nil

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"Date is: %@",dateString);
```

Output:

```
Date is: 2012-12-20 12:58:58
```